# incorrect logistic regression output

Tags: r

I'm doing logistic regression on Boston data with a column high.medv (yes/no) which indicates if the median house pricing given by column medv is either more than 25 or not.

Below is my code for logistic regression.

```
high.medv <- ifelse(Boston$medv>25, "Y", "N") # Applying the desired
```

`condition to medv and storing the results into a new variable called "medv.high"

```
ourBoston <- data.frame (Boston, high.medv)
ourBoston$high.medv <- as.factor(ourBoston$high.medv)
attach(Boston)
# 70% of data <- Train
train2<- subset(ourBoston,sample==TRUE)
# 30% will be Test
test2<- subset(ourBoston, sample==FALSE)
glm.fit <- glm (high.medv ~ lstat,data = train2, family = binomial)
summary(glm.fit)
```

The output is as follows:

```
Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -22.57   48196.14       0        1
lstat             NA         NA      NA       NA

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 0.0000e+00  on 0  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 3.1675e-10  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 21
```

Also i need:
Now I'm required to use the misclassification rate as the measure of error for the two cases:

using lstat as the predictor, and

using all predictors except high.medv and medv.
but i am stuck at the regression itself

Comment: why is the output incorrect? `NA` are usually a byproduct of missing values, incorrect formatting or modelling. Share a sample of your data so we can spot the problem

Comment: The Boston data is in the MASS package, @elle - what is sample in your subset it does not seem to be a variable in the ourBoston df

Comment: @FelipeAlvarenga - The data is available in library(MASS) Boston, 'NA is the wrong output which an error with the formatting; can you please help me to rectify that error

Comment: @Mike - The variable here which I am talking about is 'high.medv' which I have created (1st four lines of my code).

Comment: @FelipeAlvarenga I did manage to get rid of errors though, there was some mistake in my sampling. But it will be great if someone can still help me with the later (misclassifiication) part

Answer (score 0):

With every classification algorithm, the art relies on choosing the threshold upon which you will determine whether the the result is `positive` or `negative`.

When you `predict` your outcomes in the `test` data set you estimate probabilities of the response variable being either 1 or 0. Therefore, you need to the tell where you are gonna cut, the `threshold`, at which the prediction becomes 1 or 0.

A high threshold is more conservative about labeling a case as positive, which makes it less likely to produce false positives and more likely to produce false negatives. The opposite happens for low thresholds.

The usual procedure is to plot the rates that interests you, e.g., true positives and false positives against each other, and then choose what is the best rate for you.

```
set.seed(666)
# simulation of logistic data
x1 = rnorm(1000)            # some continuous variables 
z  = 1 + 2*x1               # linear combination with a bias
pr = 1/(1 + exp(-z))        # pass through an inv-logit function
y  = rbinom(1000, 1, pr)    

df       = data.frame(y = y, x1 = x1)
df$train = 0
df$train[sample(1:(2*nrow(df)/3))] = 1

df$new_y = NA
# modelling the response variable
mod = glm(y ~ x1, data = df[df$train == 1,], family = "binomial")
df$new_y[df$train == 0] = predict(mod, newdata = df[df$train == 0,], type = 'response') # predicted probabilities

dat = df[df$train==0,] # test data
```

To use missclassification error to evaluate your model, first you need to set up a threshold. For that, you can use the `roc` function from `pROC` package, which calculates the rates and provides the corresponding thresholds:

```
library(pROC)

rates =roc(dat$y, dat$new_y)
plot(rates) # visualize the trade-off
```

[image]

```
rates$specificity # shows the ratio of true negative over overall negatives
rates$thresholds # shows you the corresponding thresholds

dat$jj = as.numeric(dat$new_y>0.7) # using 0.7 as a threshold to indicate that we predict y = 1
table(dat$y, dat$jj) # provides the miss classifications given 0.7 threshold
      0   1
  0  86  20
  1  64 164
```

The accuracy of your model can be computed as the ratio of the number of observations you got right against the size of your sample.